# Warning: Creating default object... when altering Customize panels

Tags: customization, themes, widgets, options

I'm trying to move my theme's [only] widget area outside of WP 4.0's nested "Widgets" panel by doing the following:

```
$footer_widgets_section = $wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-footer_widgets' );
$footer_widgets_section->panel = '';
```

The key is to reset the panel to empty, rather than `widgets`. However, I'm getting a PHP warning: **`Warning: Creating default object from empty value in ...`** (the second line of my above code).

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `$wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-footer_widgets' )` was returning an Array, although a quick `print_r()` makes it seem as though it was an Object.

Anyhow. Simple fix: cast it to an object.

```
$footer_widgets_section = (object) $wp_customize->get_section( 'sidebar-widgets-footer_widgets' );
$footer_widgets_section->panel = '';
```